# use a modifier or provide an object in an upsert query

Tags: mongodb, upsert

In my upsert request, I'd like to both:

- update the object in place if it's there, aka

  ```
  db.somecollection.update({x: 1}, {$inc: {x: 1}});
  ```
- provide a new object if it's not there, aka

  ```
  db.somecollection.update({x: 1}, {whole: 0, new: 'yata', object: 42});
  ```

Is there a way to do that ?

The problem is that upsert seems to work only if you already provide an object in the first place, not a modifier.

edit: I'll be more specific.

I want to update objects of the form

```
{_id: 12, a: 123, b: 234, c: 345}
```

my update is just an increment of 1 on one of `a`, `b` or `c`. If the object is not in the base then I'd like to create an object of the form

```
{_id: 13, a: 1, b: 0, c: 0}
```

if `a` was the field I was trying to increment.

Now, if I read the manual correctly, I can write

```
db.somecollection.update({_id: 12}, {$inc: {a: 1}}, true);
```

which will work fine to update my `a` field but which will not create the fields `b` and `c` if the object doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upserts can work with modifiers; the modifier gets applied to the selector/criteria object when a new document needs to be created.  See [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-UpsertswithModifiers).  But you do need to set the `upsert` parameter to `true` in your `update` call:

```
db.somecollection.update({x: 1}, {$inc: {x: 1}}, true);
```

**UPDATE**

To get the behavior you're looking for:

```
db.somecollection.update({_id: 12}, {$inc: {a: 1, b: 0, c: 0}}, true);
```

Comment: please see my edit. Sorry for not having asked a complete enough question in the first place ;(

Comment: clever, thanks! Seems limited though. I don't get why instead of a boolean as third argument, an object isn't required, with null if one whishes a normal update. Anyway...